# How can I update a document's nested array of object item by 1?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to update a mongoose document with the help of `findOneAndUpdate` but I'm unable to do so. The document looks like this in the database:

```
{
    'docId': 1001,
    'totalViews': 3,
    'docInfo': [
         {
             id: 1,
             views: 2  
         },
         {
             id: 2,
             views: 1  
         }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to update `totalViews` by 1 which will make the total count to be 4. And I also need to update the second object's `views` property by 1 in `imageInfo` array. Which will have a views count of 2.

I tried doing this by first fetching the whole document with the help of:

```
const doc = await Doc.find({ docId: 1001 });
```

Then found the index of the `docInfo` array item which needs to be updated. Which is the object with id 2.

```
const docIndex = doc[0].docInfo.findIndex( item => {
      return item.id === 2;
});
```

Then used `findOneAndUpdate` to update the items:

```
await Doc.findOneAndUpdate(
      { docId: 1001, "docInfo.id": 2 },
      {
            $set: {
                  [ `docInfo.${2}.views` ]: 1++,
                  'totalViews': 1++ 
            }
      }, { new: true }
);
```

With this I'm getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is invalid, you can use [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator to increment a number, and don't need to find a query as well,

```
await Doc.findOneAndUpdate(
  { docId: 1001, "docInfo.id": 2 },
  {
    $inc: {
      'docInfo.$.views': 1,
      'totalViews': 1
    }
  }, 
  { new: true }
);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ybm90hDw0U3)